# Can create NSAlert without button in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm a newbie in Cocoa. I want to create a messagebox in cocoa same in iOS without any button. Messagebox auto close after NSTimer. I used below code but it always add OK button.

```
alert = [[[NSAlert alloc] init] autorelease];
// [alert addButtonWithTitle: @"OK"];
[alert setMessageText: @"Attention!!! This a critical Alert."];
[alert setInformativeText:@"Scanning..."];
[alert setAlertStyle: NSInformationalAlertStyle];

NSTimer *myTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval: 17.0
                                           target:self
                                         selector: @selector(killWindow:) userInfo:nil
                                                             repeats:NO];

[[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:myTimer forMode:NSModalPanelRunLoopMode];

int choice = 0;
choice = [alert runModal];
if(choice != 0)
    [myTimer invalidate];
```

KillWindow function:

```
-(void) killWindow: (NSTimer *) theTimer
{
    NSLog(@"killWindow");
    [[alert window] close];
}
```

And when alert close, my app can not click any button or interaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSAlert is designed to be used for application or window-modal display of a message with buttons for user dismissal.  It is not designed for displaying windows with no buttons; you should not use it this way.

You should use a custom NSWindow/NSPanel.  If you want it to block the window/application, then you will need to run your own modal session.  Stop the modal session from your timer callback with [`abortModal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSApplication/abortModal), in addition to closing the window as you do above.  This explains why you aren't getting any further events when the alert closes — the modal session is still running.

See [How Modal Windows Work](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/WinPanel/Concepts/UsingModalWindows.html) for more information.

Comment: [[NSApplication sharedApplication] beginSheet: scanningPanel
                                   modalForWindow: window
                                    modalDelegate: self
                                   didEndSelector: @selector(sheetDidEnd:returnCode:contextInfo:)
                                      contextInfo: nil];
    
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] runModalForWindow: scanningPanel];

Comment: I created custom NSpanel but i don't know how to set NSTimer for it. Can you help me? thanks much

Answer (score 6):

Maybe in 2013 the answer is no. However, in current SDK (Xcode 7.0 with OS X 10.11), you can simply add "" by addButtonWithTitle(""), then the button will not show.

Comment: This answer is not backwards compatible and doesn't work on 10.9 and potentially others @Lê Tấn Thành has a better more compatible solution for those of us who are stuck being backwards to ancient versions

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you can, you add new button. After, you get it and hiden it :). My code

```
NSAlert* alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"Loading...."];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
NSButton *button =  [[alert buttons] objectAtIndex:0];
[button setHidden:YES];
[alert setAccessoryView:[self viewLoadingReadFile]];
[alert setAlertStyle:NSWarningAlertStyle];
[alert runModal];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look at [`MBProgressHUD`](https://github.com/matej/MBProgressHUD). My solution to this exact problem using `MBProgressHUD`.

```
+ (void)showMessage:(NSString *)message forDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration withTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    UIWindow *window     = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
    MBProgressHUD *hud   = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
    hud.mode             = MBProgressHUDModeText;
    hud.labelText        = title;
    hud.detailsLabelText = message;

    hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:duration];
}
```

After some user testing, it was decided that users didn't like a long duration message which they couldn't dismiss.

```
+ (void)showMessage:(NSString *)message forDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration withTitle:(NSString *)title
{
    if (duration < 3.0) {
        UIWindow *window     = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow;
        MBProgressHUD *hud   = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:window animated:YES];
        hud.mode             = MBProgressHUDModeText;
        hud.labelText        = title;
        hud.detailsLabelText = message;

        hud.removeFromSuperViewOnHide = YES;
        [hud hide:YES afterDelay:duration];
    } else {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                            message:message
                                                           delegate:nil
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];

        int64_t delayInSeconds = duration;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:alertView.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: No, i implement MAC app not iOS app.

Comment: @JosonDaniel Sorry, my bad. Still, the underlying code is a model you can base your solution from.

Answer (score 0):

after you close the alert window you have to abort modal as well with [NSApp abortModal]

Now it is just a matter of hiding that button. To do this, after you instantiated the alert, you could just scan among all of alert.window.contentView.subviews for the NSButton which has the title "OK" and hide it.

Disclaimer: this is a quick, ugly hack but it works... for now. Use at your own risk